# Should I / And how to update qt client?

Tags: client

On windows should I and how to update qt client?

(btw I'm running dogecoin qt client but it's pretty alike)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep Bitcoin-Qt up to date since the developers occasionally make changes to some of the rules (such as the minimum transaction fee).  It is easy to update - just replace everything in the Bitcoin-Qt install directory (don't touch the Bitcoin-Qt data directory).